# Youtube Video not playable on click of transperent background image from JW Player

Tags: asp.net, youtube, jwplayer

We are facing a issue in JW player while making a youtube video playable on click of a transparent image which will be on top of the video. Works fine on click when we are using a video plays from a physical path.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    videoUrl = "<%=strHomeTOpVideo%>";
                    jwplayer('playerYinHVRkPdrqk').setup({
                        file: videoUrl,
                        image: "<%=strVideoBgImg%>",
                        width: '100%',
                        aspectratio: '16:7',
                        controls: 'true',
                        autostart: 'true',
                        repeat: 'true',
                        primary: 'flash',
                        ga: {
                            idstring: "title",
                            trackingobject: "pageTracker"
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script> 
             <script type='text/javascript'>
                 $(document).ready(function () {
                     $("#MainbgImage").click(function () {
                         videoUrl = "<%=strHomeTOpVideo%>";
                         file: videoUrl,
                         jwplayer('playerYinHVRkPdrqk').play(true);
                     });
                 });
             </script>
```

Here in the first scripting tag i am passing the video URL works for PC's without any click of the background image. But for mobile devices JW player doesn't support auto play so in the second script i have given a click functionality which indeed play the same  video configured in the first script tag. Now i need the same kind of functionality works also for youtube video which we are unable to make it play on click. For reference here is our staging url using youtube video in the main page.

http://demo3.devtpit.com/
JW Player Version : 6.10.4906

Comment: It isn't JW Player that doesn't support autoplay. On a mobile device, autoplay is disabled by the device itself, and for good reason - no one wants his smartphone to start playing some loud video while he's quietly browsing during a boring meeting. So you may be just chasing a phantom, here.

Comment: Indeed, not supported in html5 <video>, natively.

Comment: Fine not to be auto played in mobile devices.Should at least work on click. But the youtube video doesn't play even when i click on the transparent image which is actually overlapping the youtube video play button. But when i am passing a video from a physical path, it plays on click of that transparent image ("#MainbgImage") as per my script mentioned in the first thread. How to overcome my problem to play youtube video on click of that image?

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one who doesn't get it, but why are you putting a transparent image over the video player in the first place? What is this accomplishing?

Comment: To fake a click possibly?

Comment: Transperent image over the video is the client requirement.

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: For crystal kind of text on the video, they requested us to use transparent image on the video. Client is not satisfied with our condition of not using transparent image when YouTube video should be shown. For reference please navigate to http://uat.trinity.org.sg/ and observe the video on the home page.

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: The issue is as i mentioned, onclick on transperent window to load a youtube video is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

Autostart doesn't work on mobile devices at all.

From JW Player documentation:

> Note that autostarting does not work on mobile phones (Android, iOS), since a fullscreen video takeover would be a jarring experience. Video also swiftly depletes 3G/4G bandwidth allowances.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428525-autostarting-on-page-load

Comment: To clarify (again): this is not a limitation of JW Player. No script can (or should be able to) defeat the device's own restriction of autoplay.

Comment: Indeed, not supported in html5 <video>, natively.